# UnauthorizedAccessException : UNC Access from web app with app pool using service account

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-7

I'm trying to access a network share `\\\\ip\c$\imp\` from a web app.

- AppPool is using a domain service account for identity.
- Domain service account has full access to \ip\c$\imp\
- AppPool is running in integrated mode - framework 4.0.

But I still get `System.UnauthorizedAccessException.` Any idea why?

```
FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes("\\ip\c$\imp\testfile.txt");
if ((attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
{
     Console.WriteLine("read-only file");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("not read-only file");
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code showing how you're accessing the share?

Comment: you need to escape your backslashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is failing if ip in \ip\c$\imp\testfile.txt is the same ip of the webserver that the app is running on, otherwise it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've forgotten to escape the backslashes in the path.

A general purpose tool for tracking down problems such as this one is the Windows Sysinternals Process Monitor [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).  Set up a filter for your application (or for part of the path name, such as Path contains `file.txt`) and see what turns up.  In the case of incorrectly escaped characters, you'll see a mangled pathname.

Comment: Backslashes are not needed.